# preventing default response in express

Tags: node.js, express, client-server, httpresponse

```
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post("/api/",(req, res) => {

  const pyshell = new PythonShell("current.py");

  pyshell.on("message", function (message) {
    return res.json({result: message})
  });

  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    }
  });
// here it sends responses automatically
});

app.listen(3000);
```

whenever I run this code, I get `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error. The `pyshell.on()` is an event and I want to send response only there. So, how do I prevent the default / automatic response that is sent?? I'm a beginner to node and express.

Comment: this usual means you are sending more then one request to the client. What does your code look like below the comment `//here it sends responses automatically`

Comment: actually there is no code. but i think since the response winds up there automatically .https://github.com/Joe-Ralph/codeitksscode/blob/master/index.js here is the full code and i assume u meant more than one response there

Comment: There is no automatic response in Express.  So, you apparently have some code somewhere that is sending more than one response or your python app sends multiple messages causing you to send multiple responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surely because pyshell returns multiple messages.

So in the next code, the messages are stored in an array.

The array is send, when the pyshell is finish.

```
app.post("/api/",(req, res) => {

  const pyshell = new PythonShell("current.py");
  let messages = []

  pyshell.on("message", function (message) {
    messages.push(message)
  });

  pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err) {
     console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.json({result: messages})
    }
  });
// here it sends responses automatically
});
```